# There are random coins on the table. Prove that we can find a coin that touches no more than 5 others.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I can prove that when all coins have the same radius, we can find a coin that touches no more than 3 others.

Comment: "maximal ideals"  deals with higher concepts of algebra. I have replaced this tag by "geometry".

Comment: By putting the problem statement only in the title you invite confusion.  Please use the body of the Question to give a full problem statement.

Comment: This is an interesting problem with a very elegant solution (far better than John's), but please add the question in the post body and also give more details of what you've tried so that we can reopen the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This problem has to do with the planar graph.

Two coins are ''connected'' if they touch each other. Clearly we get planar graph and it is well known that it has a vertex of degree at most 5.

Comment: Thank you very much for the beautiful  and simple solution.

Comment: Now now, @JohnWatson  be patient.  It is the asker's prerogative to accept an answer (or not), and it is perfectly reasonable for the asker to wait to do so in any case.  At very very low levels of  rep, new users cannot upvote a question asked.  In any case, please try to refrain from suggesting a particular user upvote and accept your answer (especially when you do so only one-two hours after the question was posted.

Comment: The fact that every planar graph has vertex degree at most 5 is no easier to prove than the original question...